# HttpOnly cookie, ajax request and server-side security in a js client application

Tags: security, ajax-request, cookie-httponly

I have a js client applcation that uses an http-only cookie to store the currently authenticated user's credentials. The application uses the data in the cookie to perform the per-request authentication.

However, the application does make ajax requests that unfortunately do not include the cookie. When the server comes to process these requests, it believes it has no cookie, therefore there is no authenticated user and performs redirect to the login page. Still, the cookie is there and all standard http requests work as expected.

Is there any easy workaround for this issue? What is the recommended practice in such scenarios?

Comment: Have you tried using fiddler to check if the cookie is sent back and forth? Also "http-only" flag on cookies is not respected by all browsers. Try posting some sample code.

Comment: Even if the cookie is HttpOnly, it will still be passed for AJAX requests (even if the JS itself cannot read it).

Comment: The issue was caused by zepto js library. In general, the described scenario should work and when switched to jQuery, the problem is no more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused because of `zepto` library being used, which had the particular problem of not passing the cookie (some known issue of the library). When jQuery was used instead, all worked as expected.

Comment: Could you post the link to the issue opened in Zepto project?

Comment: @PaquitoSoft, I'll try to find relevant info and update the answer, but it was a colleague of mine that diagnosed the case. What was important for us was that it was OK with jQuery, so we dropped zepto.

Comment: In my case, the problem was solved using the 'withCredentials' attribute in the xhr object. You can check this link out to find out more info: https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/issues/274

Comment: @PaquitoSoft, thanks for the information, I'll update the answer with the link, if relevant.